# ChakraUI: How to set the checkbox color in a checked state

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, chakra-ui

I'm using a ChakraUI Checkbox as follows:

```
export function CheckItem({ color, checked, label, onChange }: CheckItemProps) {
  return (
    <Checkbox
      iconColor="white"
      borderColor={color}
      isChecked={checked}
      onChange={onChange}
      size="lg"
    >
      <Text fontSize="12px">{label}</Text>
    </Checkbox>
  );
}
```

How do I set the box color of my checkbox when checked?

- Using `bg` sets the background of the entire container including the text.
- Using `color` sets the color of the text.
- Using `colorScheme` doesn't work because I'm using hex values, not colors from my theme.
- `borderColor` works as I'd expect in the unchecked state until I check the box, then it's back to the default blue fill.

I've tried all other prop names with the word `color` in it and none of them work.

I would expect something in the end to look like this:

```
export function CheckItem({ color, checked, label, onChange }: CheckItemProps) {
  return (
    <Checkbox
      _checked={{
        // I don't know what prop to put here...
      }}
      iconColor="white"
      borderColor={color}
      isChecked={checked}
      onChange={onChange}
      size="lg"
    >
      <Text fontSize="12px">{label}</Text>
    </Checkbox>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a css selector in `_checked` to set the needed styles for the control. The reason `_checked={{ background: "red" }}` doesn't work is because those styles are applied to the `container` part when the checkbox is checked. Hence the css selector is needed.

```
export function CheckItem({ color, checked, label, onChange }: CheckItemProps) {
  return (
    <Checkbox
     _checked={{
        "& .chakra-checkbox__control": { background: "red" }
      }}     
      iconColor="white"
      borderColor={color}
      isChecked={checked}
      onChange={onChange}
      size="lg"
    >
      <Text fontSize="12px">{label}</Text>
    </Checkbox>
  );
}
```

*You’ll still need to update the border color and pseudo states (hover, focus, etc.) styles but you should be able to do that inside there as well.*

Comment: how make it with theme config?

Comment: Good solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution is to extend the theme with your custom color.
From testing, the only way I could get the results that you want was a combination of `iconColor` and `colorScheme`

```
  <Checkbox size='lg' iconColor='black' colorScheme='orange' defaultChecked>
```

By extending your [theme](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme) or by overriding the default, you can create your own colors that you can then pass into the colorScheme.

Comment: That is a work around if I know what colors I will be expecting. The problem I have is that I need to be able to pass any hex values to the checkbox, and extending my theme the support `16581375` different variations isn't viable.

Comment: Hmm I dont think it is possible without creating your own custom checkbox component. I also tried using the sx property but it does not allow me to change the accent color.

Comment: I was about to open an issue with ChakraUI but saw you already opened.

Comment: Well I'm glad to know I'm not stupid :D Yeah I've opened an issue and linked to this SO Question.